# python pandas dataframe : fill nans with a conditional mean

Tags: python, pandas, nan, fill

I have the following dataframe:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Cat' : ['A', 'A', 'A','B', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
                        'Vals' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, np.nan, np.nan]})

    Cat   Vals
0   A     1
1   A     2
2   A     3
3   B     4
4   B     5
5   A   NaN
6   B   NaN
```

And I want indexes `5` and `6` to be filled with the conditional mean of 'Vals' based on the 'Cat' column, namely `2` and `4.5`

The following code works fine:

```
means = df.groupby('Cat').Vals.mean()
for i in df[df.Vals.isnull()].index:
    df.loc[i, 'Vals'] = means[df.loc[i].Cat]

    Cat   Vals
0   A     1
1   A     2
2   A     3
3   B     4
4   B     5
5   A     2
6   B   4.5
```

But I'm looking for something nicer, like

```
df.Vals.fillna(df.Vals.mean(Conditionally to column 'Cat'))
```

Edit: I found this, which is one line shorter, but I'm still not happy with it:

```
means = df.groupby('Cat').Vals.mean()
df.Vals = df.apply(lambda x: means[x.Cat] if pd.isnull(x.Vals) else x.Vals, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 7):

We wish to "associate" the `Cat` values with the missing NaN locations.
In Pandas such associations are always done via the index.
So it is natural to set `Cat` as the index:

```
df = df.set_index(['Cat'])
```

Once this is done, then `fillna` works as desired:

```
df['Vals'] = df['Vals'].fillna(means)
```

To return `Cat` to a column, you could then of course use `reset_index`:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Cat' : ['A', 'A', 'A','B', 'B', 'A', 'B'], 
     'Vals' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, np.nan, np.nan]})

means = df.groupby(['Cat'])['Vals'].mean()
df = df.set_index(['Cat'])
df['Vals'] = df['Vals'].fillna(means)
df = df.reset_index()
print(df)
```

yields

```
  Cat  Vals
0   A   1.0
1   A   2.0
2   A   3.0
3   B   4.0
4   B   5.0
5   A   2.0
6   B   4.5
```

Comment: Not worth a separate answer, but `df["Vals"].fillna(df.groupby("Cat")["Vals"].transform("mean"))` would avoid the need to change index.

Comment: I am wondering why you  set `Cat` as the index? It seems df['Vals'] = df['Vals'].fillna(means) will produce the same result without setting and resetting the index.

Comment: @JoeR: It won't because Cat takes values 'A' and 'B'. The asker wants to fill `nan` against A (or B) with the mean obtained from the values against A (or B)

Comment: @Kartik Just run the code and you will see, the results are the same.

Comment: @DSM That's exactly what I was looking for (and it's faster), I didn't know the use of `transform`. Thanks!

Comment: @DSM: Great answer! Sorry by mistake i removed upvote, can't upvote again.

Comment: @DSM your comment is worth a separate answer, very helpful!