# Pandas Replace NaN values based on random sample of values conditional on another column

Tags: python, pandas, random, imputation

Say I have a dataframe like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

df = {}
df['x'] = np.concatenate([np.random.uniform(0, 5, 4), np.random.uniform(5, 10, 4)])
df['y'] = np.concatenate([[0] * 4, [1] * 4])
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df.loc[len(df) + 1] = [np.NaN, 0]
df.loc[len(df) + 1] = [np.NaN, 1]
df
Out[232]: 
           x    y
0   2.744068  0.0
1   3.575947  0.0
2   3.013817  0.0
3   2.724416  0.0
4   7.118274  1.0
5   8.229471  1.0
6   7.187936  1.0
7   9.458865  1.0
9        NaN  0.0
10       NaN  1.0
```

What I want to do is fill in the `NaN` values based on a random sample of `x` values based on the `y` value.

For example, in row 9 where `y` is 0, I want to replace the `NaN` with a number randomly sampled only from `x` values where the value of `y` is 0.  Effectively, I'd be sampling from this list:

```
df[df['y'] == 0]['x'].dropna().values.tolist()
Out[233]: [2.7440675196366238, 3.5759468318620975, 3.0138168803582195, 2.724415914984484]
```

And similarly for row 10, I'd sample only based on 'x' values where `y` is 1, rather than 0.  I can't figure out a way to do it programmatically (at least, in a way that isn't bad practice, such as iterating through dataframe rows).

I've consulted [Pandas: Replace NaN Using Random Sampling of Column Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384934/pandas-replace-nan-using-random-sampling-of-column-values), which shows me how I would randomly sample from all values in a column, but I need the random sample to be conditional on another column's distinct values.  I've also seen answers for replacing NaNs with a conditional mean ([such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33457191/python-pandas-dataframe-fill-nans-with-a-conditional-mean)), but I'm looking to randomly sample, rather than use the mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `transform` with `choice`

I forgo efficiency for readability.  Note that I generate a random choice for each row but only pick the number I need to fill in the nulls.  Theoretically, I can make it such that I only pick random numbers for those missing values.

```
def f(s):
    mask = s.isna()
    return np.where(mask, np.random.choice(s[~mask], len(s)), s)

df.assign(x=df.groupby('y')['x'].transform(f))

           x    y
0   2.744068  0.0  # <━┓
1   3.575947  0.0  #   ┃
2   3.013817  0.0  #   ┃
3   2.724416  0.0  #   ┃
4   7.118274  1.0  #   ┃
5   8.229471  1.0  # <━╋━┓
6   7.187936  1.0  #   ┃ ┃
7   9.458865  1.0  #   ┃ ┃
9   2.744068  0.0  # <━┛ ┃
10  8.229471  1.0  # <━━━┛
```

---

Slightly more obtuse but only picking as many as we need.

```
def f(s):
    out = s.to_numpy().copy()
    mask = s.isna().to_numpy()
    out[mask] = np.random.choice(out[~mask], mask.sum())
    return out

df.assign(x=df.groupby('y')['x'].transform(f))

           x    y
0   2.744068  0.0  # <━┓
1   3.575947  0.0  #   ┃
2   3.013817  0.0  #   ┃
3   2.724416  0.0  #   ┃
4   7.118274  1.0  # <━╋━┓
5   8.229471  1.0  #   ┃ ┃
6   7.187936  1.0  #   ┃ ┃
7   9.458865  1.0  #   ┃ ┃
9   2.744068  0.0  # <━┛ ┃
10  7.118274  1.0  # <━━━┛
```